# display result sql in columns

Tags: php, eclipse

I would like to display the results of my sql in three columns like the format below.

How is it possible? Should I add table with tr and td? or div in my code?

```
CategoryName1     CategoryName2     CategoryName3   
subcategoryN      subcategoryN      subcategoryN



<?php 
  foreach ($resultLang as $oneRec)
  {             
    $catid= $oneRec["categoryID"];


    echo"<strong>".$oneRec["categoryName"]."</strong><br>";


    $sqlCmd2 ="SELECT subcategories.subCatID,subcategories.subCatName
              FROM subcategories
              JOIN categories
              ON subcategories.categoryID=categories.categoryID
              JOIN languages
              ON categories.languageID = languages.languageID
              WHERE languages.languageID =:lang
              AND categories.categoryID=:cboCat";
    $prepQuery2 = $conn ->prepare($sqlCmd2);
    $prepQuery2->bindParam(":lang",$langTemp, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $prepQuery2->bindParam(":cboCat",$catid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $prepQuery2->execute();
    $resultLang2= $prepQuery2->fetchAll();

    foreach ($resultLang2 as $oneRec)
    {
        $subCatid=$oneRec["subCatID"];

        echo "<a href='displaysubcategory.php?subcat=?$subCatid'>".$oneRec["subCatName"]."</a></br>";

    }               
    echo "<br>";

  }
```

Comment: Format your question properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
echo"<ul class='maincats'>";
  foreach ($resultLang as $oneRec)
  {             
    $catid= $oneRec["categoryID"];


    echo"<li>";
    echo"<strong>".$oneRec["categoryName"]."</strong>";

    $sqlCmd2 ="SELECT subcategories.subCatID,subcategories.subCatName
              FROM subcategories
              JOIN categories
              ON subcategories.categoryID=categories.categoryID
              JOIN languages
              ON categories.languageID = languages.languageID
              WHERE languages.languageID =:lang
              AND categories.categoryID=:cboCat";
    $prepQuery2 = $conn ->prepare($sqlCmd2);
    $prepQuery2->bindParam(":lang",$langTemp, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $prepQuery2->bindParam(":cboCat",$catid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $prepQuery2->execute();
    $resultLang2= $prepQuery2->fetchAll();
    if($resultLang2) {
        echo"<ul class='subcats'>";
        foreach ($resultLang2 as $oneRec)
        {
            $subCatid=$oneRec["subCatID"];
            echo"<li>";
            echo "<a href='displaysubcategory.php?subcat=?$subCatid'>".$oneRec["subCatName"]."</a>";
            echo"</li>";
        } 
        echo"</ul>";
    }
    echo"</li>";

  }
echo"</ul>";
```

After that create some CSS rules for maincats and subcats class using float, display:inline-block properties according to your design theme.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what eclipse tag is, but what I normally do is:

```
 $header = "";
 $data = "";
foreach ($resultLang2 as $oneRec)
{
    $header .= "<td>".$oneRec['field']."</td>";
    $data .= "<tr><td>".$oneRec['someData']."</td><td>".$oneRec['someOtherData']."</td></tr>";
}

 echo "<table>";
 echo "<tr>".$header."</tr>";
 echo $data;
 echo "</table>";
```